# How can I save the anonymous firebase credential to another place than localstorage?

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am creating a app with cordova, ionic3 and firebase. The app does not require to sign in, since the user will be automatically signed in as an **anonymous** firebase user. The problem is that firebase saves the anonymous user credential in the localstorage. And in the cordova world, this means that it is not 100% reliable.

In the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html) it says:

> iOS stores localStorage data in a location that may be cleaned out by the OS when space is required.

This means the data might get lost since I am only using the anonymous login from firebase. I know that I can link the accounts together, but in my case I do not want to do this.

My question is; Can you store the firebase **anonymous** auth token somewhere else so it can be 100% reliable for IOS users?

Comment: what about to get the uuid and store the pair <uuid,token> at firebase? If the token is not present at local storage, you could recover it from database according the uuid.

Comment: I have thought about just copying the token refresh token from localstorage to sqlite, but have not tried it yet. I also thought about replacing the localstorage object with something that persist better on ios. But I do not want to play with the native objects. That could lead to confusing problems.
I think I'll just wait until they open-source their project.

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted Firebase staff and they say that this is not possible at the moment. However, this could change in the future. They have plans of open-sourcing their SDKs in the near future, which would make it possible to change this behaviour.

Here is also a [response](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/rH1BttDsqWA) from one of their engineers

Comment: The latest firebase version do support changing the auth-state-persistence (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence). But not to SQLite. :(